# Explanation of the difference operator $\mathscr{N} \textbf{y}(x_n)$ used in numerical analysis

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

In books about numerical methods one can get across the difference operator (methods for numerical solution of ODE's): $\mathscr{N} \textbf{y}(x_n)$. However in all the books I have only the example usage on Euler method is given without any explanation how to use it.

$$\mathscr{N} \textbf{u}(t_n)\equiv \frac{\textbf{u}(t_n)-\textbf{u}(t_{n-1})}{h_n}-\textbf{f}(t_{n-1},\textbf{u}(t_{n-1}))$$
where $\textbf{u}$ is a mesh function, $t_n$ are computational steps (independent variable) with $n=0,1,...$, $\textbf{f}$ is the derivative of $\textbf{u}$ function  $\frac{d\textbf{u}}{d t}=\textbf{f}(t,\textbf{u}(t))$, $h_n$ is the step size.

Will this operator have different shape for let's say trapezoidal rule? Does it's form is simply rearranged numerical approximation scheme? How to use it to show the truncation error of the trapezoidal rule?

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{h_n \to 0} \frac{u(t_n) - u(t_{n-1})}{h_n}$ is precisely the definition of $\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t}$. By stopping this before $h_n$ quite gets to zero, assuming your function isn't too nasty, we get an approximation for the derivative that can be directly calculated (taking limits isn't something you can really do with a computer).

It is related to the trapezoidal rule, which is a way to approximate integration, although only somewhat roughly. If we start with our equation

\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t} = f(t,u(t)),
\end{equation}

Then by the fundamental theorem of calculus,

\begin{equation}
u(t_n) - u(t_{n-1}) = \int_{t_{n-1}}^{t_n}f(s,u(s))\mathrm{d}s \approx (t_n - t_{n-1})\left(\frac{f(t_n,u(t_n)) - f(t_{n-1},u(t_{n-1}))}{2}\right),
\end{equation}

with the last equality coming from the trapezoidal rule. Rearranging gives

\begin{equation}
\frac{u(t_n) - u(t_{n-1})}{h_n} = \frac{1}{2}(f(t_n,u(t_n)) - f(t_{n-1},u(t_{n-1}))),
\end{equation}
which is superficially similar to the scheme you describe (which is called 'forward Euler', as to calculate the value at time $t_n$ you need only know the value of $u$ at time $t_{n-1}$), however, the one we've just derived uses an average of $f$ at $t_n$ and $t_{n-1}$ as opposed to just the latter. This in fact will make it more accurate but is harder to implement as it involves solving an algebraic equation to each time step to account for the unknown $f(t_n,u(t_{n}))$ on the RHS.

To get a truncation error in terms of the stepsize, which I think is what yo're driving at in the last bit, remember than you can use Taylor's theorem to expand 
\begin{equation}
u(t_n) = u(t_{n-1} + h_n) = u(t_{n-1}) + h_nu'(t{n-1}) + \frac{h_n^2}{2}u''(t_{n-1}) + O(h_n^3),
\end{equation}

which I think will be enough terms to get the result out if you just plug it in. If not, though, you know what to do.

Comment: In your answer there is actually nothing about the difference operator usage

Comment: @Misery In that case I don't really understand what you're asking. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I am interested in the formalism of using the difference operator

Comment: @Misery it's used whenever you want to approximate a first derivative to solve an equation numerically and an $O(h)$ truncation error is good enough (also there are considerations like stability which mean it's rarely used in practice but it is a good introductory example) You can approximate higher order derivatives by concatenating finite difference operators over a suitable number of points (a second derivative requires three points, etc.). They also crop up in things like elliptic regularity theory where they can be used in the limit to show the existence of a derivative.